# RealmQuery vs RealmResult

Tags: android, realm

what are the differences between `RealmQuery`and a `RealmResult`?

More concretely:

On a `RealmQuery`I can filter with `equalTo`, but I have to pass the properties name as a `String`, which is error-prone.
A `RealmResult` is a `List`, so I can filter with the `filter` method, which is way more convenient, because I have acces to the properties.

Are there any performance or memory impacts, if always do;

Java Code:

```
realm.where(realmModel.class).findAll().filter(...)
```

and don't use the RealmQuerys `equalTo()` and `in()` methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
realm.where(realmModel.class).findAll().filter(...)
```

That `filter()` comes from `List<T>` interface, meaning you are not actually executing your query inside the Realm database. You're just running a `filter()` for every single element that the `findAll()` returns, which is every element, instead of an actual filtered list that is filtered by Realm (database-side).

That, and I think that `filter(new Predicate() {...` is only available API 24+.

If you don't want to use strings for field names, then [use constants instead](https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper).

> Are there any performance or memory impacts, if always do;

Yes.

In SQL terms, this would be equivalent to `SELECT * FROM TABLE` and filtering every single element by hand in memory, instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...` -- except in the Realm world.

Comment: In SQL Terms it is clear. But in Realm the elements of `RealmResult` are only references to the data - not POJOs; so are there really impacts. A `RealmQuery` must also somewhere contain references to the data.

Comment: The API Level is no problem - I'm programming in Kotlin

Comment: Filter still iterates the entire list in memory. So technically you create N proxies per filter, instead of just obtaining M < N filtered proxies; not to mention having to manually calculate the new list on any change to the results again.